# How can i create a route with waypoints in skobbler (android)

Tags: android, skmaps

I've a list of waypoints (latitude, longitude) and i want to create a route in skobbler, but i don't know if there is a method to do this.

Comment: Have you found anything @stefano

Answer (score 1):

The public SDK (free tier) does not support route via waypoints, but it might be available in the next release.

---

Edit July, 2015

As for 2015 - the SDK fully supports via point routing & navigation

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a feature called poly lines. You can find instructions to add polylines in skobbler here: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android

Look in the section titled: Adding annotations & overlays.

They even have some code snips in there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok! But i can't use the poly line for navigation turn by turn.

Comment: For calculating and displaying a route use this : http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec012

Comment: thanks! i also use this functions, but for calculate a route you need only the start and the end; while in my app i need the route cross a specified points

Comment: I dont think the free one supports way-points, you will have to do it manually. Calculate a route from your first way-point to your second way-point and plot it, then calculate a route from your second way-point to your third way-point and so on till you reach your final way-point. Plot all the routes and you will have a route through your way-points.