# Issue in setting same Start and End coordinates in routing

Tags: android, navigation, skmaps, skobbler-maps

i created application for Navigation using skobbler. Application works fine, but if i set loop route i.e Start and End coordinates are same then it start navigation and immediately end navigation. How i can handle this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should be able to solve this using waypoints. I am not sure if Skobbler supports waypoints, but I think it does (refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25850181/1840795).

Comment: I am already using viapoints!

Answer (score 0):

Right now this scenario is not supported (circuit routes or A to A routes) - we are working on an improvement in this regards but it is still in development.